# Spark - How to extract n rows from a dataset?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a pyspark dataframe of 48790 rows,  on which 37109 have [income == 0].
I want to reduce this 37109 rows to a random 10 000. So that I am left will only 10 000 rows with income == 0 (I am balancing classes for a ML algo).

How can I fetch away 10000 rows of a dataframe  ?

I tried :

```
data8 = data6.filter("income == 0")

data9 = data8.sample(False, 10000/float(data8.count()))

print data6.count(), data8.count(), data9.count()
48790 37109 10094
```

but it gives an error :

```
data10 = data6.subtract(data9)

data10.count()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3692.count.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: no default for type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7
```

Here is data6 schema :

```
StructType(List(StructField(features,VectorUDT,true),StructField(income,DoubleType,true)))
```

Comment: `take()` or `sample()` isn't working?

Comment: as I understand [take] return a list, which could blow up the memory, and I am already using [sample] here.

Answer (score 3):

I get the same problem with the spark version 2.1.0 when I have been using "except" function of DataFrame. That is very confusing, and it seems to be the bug of the "except" function.

The "except" or "subtract" operator will trigger LeftAnti plan, then will call "JoinSelection.apply" function, in which "ExtractEquiJoinKeys.unapply" function will be called, then will call "Literal.default" function, however "Literal.default" function does not support dataType of VectorUDT, it just throws a runtime exception. That is the cause of this issue.

Comment: Is there an official issue/bug report?

Comment: Don't know about that.

Comment: Looks like the issue was fixed in development: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16765